# How to select an option from dropdown using selenium in python

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation

i want to select an option using selenium from the list bellow :

[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zablZ.png)

But the problem is that there is no list to select from.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU0us.png)

my code so far :

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
 
chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
# for linux/Ubuntu only
#chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") 


browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), 
  chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get('https://www.ibm.com/demos/live/tts-demo/self-service/home')
#element = browser.find_element_by_id('downshift-2-toggle-button').click()
#select_voice = Select(element)
voice= browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="downshift-2-toggle- 
 button"]/span')
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].innerHTML = "Michael";', voice)
```

Need help!!

Comment: You need to elaborate a little further, what is the exact problem you are getting also post a code snippet to better help us understand.

Comment: Unfortunately, we need more information to answer your question. See [What should a 'minimal, reproducible example' include for problems with automating web browsers using Selenium?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405791).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the element Michael click the neural voice span and than click the tag with Michael text.

```
voice = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='downshift-2-toggle-button']/span")
voice.click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.='Michael']").click()
```

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest adding a better div xpath like //div[@id='downshift-2-menu']//div[.='Michael'].

Comment: Sometimes when running headless you need to add an user agent.